# Script Instance Checker

Tags: php, instance, cron

I have been researching on how to approach this. What I am trying to prevent is an overlapping execution of a cronjob. I would like to run my script in every minute basis because the application is support needs a constant look out. The problem is if it takes quite a long time to finish and the next cron execute will catch up.

I have searched and some posted about PID but did not get on how to do it. I cannot use lock files because it can be unreliable, tried it already.

Is there any other approach on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Get each job to write to a database in completion. Then put an if statement at the start of each script to ensure that the other script has run and completed (by checking your database).

Alternatively...

You could have your first script run your second script at the end?

Comment: I believe that cannot be. It would be like the lock file. What will happen is upon executing the script, for your answer you will insert in the database it would take a long while for a script to be finish. What if in the middle of it the cron crashed. You were unable to flag that a run was not finished. you will then always return that there is still running, which it cannot be.

Comment: Of course you would, if not entry has been made that it has completed don't run the next job. Then the next minute it will check again, if an entry is available(ie it completed) then run the script. You could then just do a simple comparision in `IF` statement to check the last run date of script 1 and script 2 and compare to work out which one needs to run next.